# How to compare elements with user index by using MSSQL and Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I created my tables in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and then I created the connection with the database in Python.

I can fetch the whole records of a table which means that I do not have any problem with the connection.
Yet I want to create a login system and I am trying to compare the input which is entered by the user and the database record for login system.

Here is my code

```
def read(conn,name,password):
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from UserList")
if(name==cursor["Username"] & password == cursor["Password"])  :
    print("A")
```

Hence, when I run it, it gives an error as

```
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MyProject/Project", line 18, in <module>
read(conn,name,password)
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MyProject/Project", line 6, in read
if(name==cursor["Username"] & password == cursor["Password"])  :
TypeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object is not subscriptable
```

What is the problem and which guide I should follow to solve this?

Comment: Side note: I *hope* that the `password` column is actually a hashed password, by a random salt, and not plain text as the code suggests it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of these cursor functions to load the results of the query into memory.

```py
cursor.execute("select * from UserList")

# get all results
results = cursor.fetchall()

# get one result
results = cursor.fetchone()

# get multiple results in chunks
results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
```

Reference:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor

"fetchone" & "fetchmany" will load the results into memory in chunks. You would then need to loop until there are no more records available.

```py
while True:
    results = cursor.fetchmany(10)
    if len(results)==0:
        break
```